# dynamic observable classes for knockout

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I am working on a reporting related project, where I need to build lot of reports rendered using KO. All data pulled using AJAX and the model is updated. Currently I am writing tons of js functions to map the models. Something like:

```
function modelx(child) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(child.Name);
    self.Relation = ko.observable(child.Relation);
    // hundred other properties
};
function modely(child) {
    var self = this;
    self.Age = ko.observable(child.Age);
    self.Relation = ko.observable(child.Relation);
    // hundred other properties
};
```

and after AJAX call, I am filling the observable arrays

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsn.length; i++)
{
    VM.modelxlist().push(new modelx(jsn[i]));
}

for (var i = 0; i < jsn1.length; i++)
{
    VM.modelylist().push(new modely(jsn1[i]));
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the definition of modelx, modely,... such that the model is automatically built without loosing the benefits of this approach while using in HTML? Of course there could be a corner case where I may not get a specific property from server, which I should check on the server side.

Also, at times I may need to add additional computed observables (just to be more flexible)

Comment: you can always make some re-usable functions to cut down repetition.

Comment: Isn`t it ( http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html ) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use knockout mapping plugin:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

You would then have something like:

```
var modelxInstance= ko.mapping.fromJS(child);
```

There are a few mapping plugins for knockout, the one i like the most is actually this one:

https://github.com/LucasLorentz/knockout.mapper

And the reason is that it is more configurable and it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) is what you want..

With ko.mapping.fromJS method u can automatically observe all the properties from your object..
Take some time to read about that..